# iOS autolayout issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

i am using xcode 6.4.
i have a view controller named "sample".The view controller contain a scroll view.The scrollview contain another view(container view).The width of container view is thrice of the width of scrollview.when the scroll view is swiping right(or left) it must show the 3 parts of the container view.I did it using paging enabled property of UIscrollview(without auto-layout).But when using auto-layout i cant find a solution.Can anybody tell me a solution for this???please explain constraints for scroll view and container view.Can anybody upload a demo???

Comment: I recommend either using a UIPagedViewController or a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView. One of these solutions should do whatever you need

Comment: @DBoyer Thanks,UIPageViewController is really working